# Getting/changing class of an element with other elements in it. JavaScript/JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I made a blog archive in the format of this:

```
+Year
   +Month
        Title
```

Sample code:

```
<ul>
    <span class="toggle">+</span>
    <li class="year">$year
          <ul>
               <span class="toggle">+</span>
               <li class="month active">$month
                    <ul>
                         <li class="title active">$title</li>
                    </ul>
               </li>
          </ul>
     </li>
</ul>
```

I used `$(this).next().toggle()`, which works fine toggling the lists, but the entire list is expanded in the beginning when the page loads, and I don't want that.

So I changed to changing class names (active/inactive). I want to change the class of the month/title lists to inactive and back when the + span is clicked. The problem is using $(this).next() doesn't work.

If I try `$(this).next().hasClass("active");`
It will return a false. Or `console.log($(this).next().attr("class"));`, which gives undefined.

`$(this).next().html();` gives:

```
<li class="month active"><span class="toggle">+</span><ul><li class="title active">...</li></ul></li></ul></li></ul>
```

The very next thing that follows the + span is the list with class of active, but it doesn't recognize the class? I don't understand why .toggle() works, but this doesn't.

What option do I have to make this work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The idea is to capture the click event on the span class and toggle active/inactive on the year so that it shows correctly. Here's some psuedo code:

```
$('.toggle').on('click', function(){
    $(this).next().toggleClass('active').toggleClass('inactive');
});
```

This will only work if the element has a class of `inactive` on page load, like this:

```
<ul>
    <span class="toggle">+</span>
    <li class="year inactive">$year
          <ul>
              <span class="toggle">+</span>
              <li class="month active">$month
                  <ul>
                     <li class="title active">$title</li>
                 </ul>
              </li>
          </ul>
     </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Thanks for replying, but I already had the toggle() part working. And yes, I have the active/inactive classes already put in before page loads. It's just the $(this).next() doesn't seem to point at the very next thing.

Comment: @J13t0u I think I've illustrated that it does point to the next thing with my fiddle. Therefore there is either additional HTML that has been omitted from the page, or your javascript does not target the correct element. It's one of the 2, though.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the script isn't targeting the correct element. Using php to generate html mixed with a lot of queries in between is quite messy. Apparently I misplaced the <ul> tags. Things fixed. I thought it was something about .next() I wasn't understanding.

Answer (score 0):

When you had your initial toggle working but it displayed the items on load, you could have set the next element (the unordered list) to

```
style="display: none"
```

As for

```
console.log($(this).next().attr("class");
```

You are missing a parenthesis:

```
console.log( $(this).next().attr("class") );
```

Comment: Right, I actually tried to put the style inside the html, but .toggle() doesn't  change the style for me. And the console.log part would be a typo on my part when I put it on here.

Answer (score 0):

Hope this helps.

By using little bit of CSS and toggling the class of `ul` to active only on click will fix your issue. Below is a working example.

```js
$('.toggle').on('click', function() {     
  $(this).parent().toggleClass('active');
});
```

```css
ul {
  list-style-type: none;
}
ul:not(#MainNode) {
  display: none;
}
ul.active > li > ul {
  display: block !important;
}
.toggle {
  cursor: pointer
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="MainNode">
  <span class="toggle">+</span>
  <li class="year">Year
    <ul>
      <span class="toggle">+</span>
      <li class="month active">Month
        <ul>
          <li class="title active">Title</li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```